# Removing a character from a PHP string using Opencart

Tags: php, string, replace, opencart, trim

I'm currently using Opencart (1.5.6.1) to run a multistore, 
I have a store that has lots of products but they all have to have the same name,
Now in the back-end I have "Blah - Tshirt 15" "Blah - Tshirt 16" and so on...

Within opencart there is a foreach loop

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
 <?php if ($product['name']) { ?>
  <?php if ($product['product_href']) { ?>
   <div class="name">
    <a href="<?php echo $product['product_href']; ?>">
     <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
    </a>
   </div>

<?php } else { ?>

<div class="name">
 <?php echo $product['name'];  ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Now the output of this on a page, does what it says, outputs the Product name "Blah - Tshirt 15"
or whatever they're called.

But what if on the page that a customer see's my client want EVERY tshirt to just say

"Blah - Tshirt"

Is there an easy way to either `str replace`, or `trim` the code to say, remove the last 1 or 2 Characters from the `$product[name]`

I'm not a huge PHP expert, i know a little, but i can't figure it out...

Comment: I think the best method is to add a new field like - `product_label` in database `product_description` and product form. Run a query to insert values to it for the existing products and show it in frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a PHP function called `substr` https://www.php.net/substr . You could use `substr($product['name'], 0, -1);` This will remove the last character. If you use `-2` it will remove the last 2 characters and so on.

`substr('yourstring'{string}, startindex{int}, endindex{int});`

Comment: I chose to use 
<?php echo substr($product['name'], 0, -2); ?>
and it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `substr($product['name'], 0, -2)` to cut the last 2 characters off a string using [substr](https://www.php.net/substr).

However, if you want to remove all numbers from a string, use regex. Like `preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $product['name']);` from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363005/how-to-remove-numbers-from-a-string-with-regex). It uses [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the last n characters with `substr($var, 0, -n)` as the others suggested. But if you want to delete "a space followed by any amount of digits at the end of the string", use regular expressions instead: `preg_replace('/ \d+$/', '', $var)`.

Answer (score 0):

In Your template just replace this line

```
<?php echo $product['name']; ?>
```

with this line

```
<?php echo substr($product['name'], 0, strpos($product['name'], '- Tshirt') + 8); ?>
```

This should lead to this result:

> Blah - Tshirt 1     ->    Blah - Tshirt
>   Blah - Tshirt 15    ->    Blah - Tshirt
>   Blah - Tshirt 150   ->    Blah - Tshirt

without the trailing space.