# How can I remove only numbers an the beginning of a string and not at the end of a string with PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace

for Example:

39P -> must become P

208Pb ->must become Pb

but:
CaSO4 -> must stay CaSO4

(not remove number in CaSO4 )

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You could use regular expressions for this, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [ltrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php).

```
$s = '208Pb';
echo ltrim($s, '0123456789');
# Pb
```

You could write a regular expression.

```
echo preg_replace('/^\d+/', '', $s);
# Pb
```

You could parse the string using [sscanf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) with a default in case it fails.

```
echo sscanf($s, '%d%s')[1] ?: $s
# Pb
```

You could use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strspn](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php).

```
echo substr($s, strspn($s, '0123456789'));
# Pb
```

You could write a little loop.

```
while ($s !== '' && is_numeric($s[0])) $s = substr($s, 1); echo $s;
# or, if your leading numbers cannot possibly be just a bunch of zeros:
while ($s > 0) $s = substr($s, 1); echo $s;
# Pb
```

Comment: this `echo preg_replace('[^\d+]', '', $s);` doesnt suits the ops task. it would remove more than it should.

Comment: Works for me. `echo preg_replace('[^\d+]', '', '39P');` => 'P' / `echo preg_replace('[^\d+]', '', '208Pb');` => 'Pb' / `echo preg_replace('[^\d+]', '', 'CaS04');` => 'CaS04'

Comment: @Dwza it is a trick of the eye.  The pattern is using `[` and `]` as pattern delimiters -- not as a negated characters class.  It works properly but will cause unnecessary eye strain to all that read the code.

Comment: ah, ok... now this make sense ^^ 
@MattRaines may use some links to testers like [this one](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/CHl#tab-preg-replace) to make it more clear...

Comment: lol at "unnecessary eye strain", @mickmackusa. Have corrected to reduce optician visits :)

Answer (score 2):

Use left trim with a ranged mask.  Similarly to how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69420637/2943403) is done.

`echo ltrim($string, '0..9');`